# Fragments inside a fragment usign two bottom navigation bars

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an app design which contains:

```
activity_main.xml
activity_sub.xml
```

activity_main.xml contains a bottom navigation bar with 5 options and a fragment as a FrameLayout.
activity_sub.xml contains a bottom navigation bar with 4 options and its own fragment (FrameLayout).

When I press on one of the bottom navigation bar options from activity_main.xml, in one instance, I want to change to activity_sub.xml.
I am doing this by using replace() function.

Once I populate my fragment with activity_sub.xml data, data from this layout cannot be removed. It is persistent, despite me changing views by using activity_sub.xml bottom navigation bar. Any of the option I chose will only draw over state from 1st option in navigation bar. Once I press on a 1st item option from navigation bar, I get a duplicate of that bottom navigation bar.

Can you support in how to properly handle fragments in this scenario?

Comment: instead of replacing. use add() then hide and show fragment according to your usecase.